# Json Parsing nested array

Tags: javascript, json

I have been referencing to this post [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json), put have had no luck in figuring this out:

i have this JSON that I get from a http request: and in my app I need to asks the Posts object.

```
    { 
      "email" : "test@email.com", 
      "username" : "rambo",
      "fullname" : "Michael Stalone",
      "posts" : [
                 { "username" : "Bad Man",  
                   "comments" : 
                      [ 
                         { "com_user" : "michael", "com_post" : "good stuff" },
                         { "com_user" : "alex", "com_post" : "hell yes" }  
                      ]  
                  }, 
                  { "username" : "CheckerTats", 
                    "comments" : [ 
                          { "com_user" : "basky", "com_post" : "wow awesome" } 
                      ] 
                  }
                ]
      }
```

I get it fine and see everything as it should be. I also notice it returns and array object so i index the varriable i assign it to: var items = data[0]. console.log(data[0]) shows this:

```
{
 "email":"test@email.com",
 "username":"rambo",
  "fullname":"Michael Stalone",
  "posts":["[object Object]","[object Object]"]
}
```

So this is all good and dandy and realize I need to take it a step further and investigate data[0]['posts'][0] which shows to be:

```
[object Object]
```

I am now almost certain that this is the first post object. I would think that data[0]['posts'][0]['username'] would give me that particular user name. To make matters worse my dev environment is an iOS Apache Cordova app, so when I run console.log on it I am returned nothing.I have assigned this to variables, uses stringify, dot notation, and am still continuously not able to access this object. I need to do so to assign it to an angular scope variable.

**EDIT:**

A new log is now returning undefined:

```
 var items = dat[0]['posts'][0];
 console.log(items['username']); // undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried console.dir() instead of console.log()?  does it show anything different?

Also, what is the backend?  do you have an http intercept defined? The only thing I can think of at the moment, if you can't get those objects to expand using console.dir(), is that somehow there is a JSON.toString (not stringify()) on those objects somewhere in the process.  Seems unlikey, but ??

Comment: In your log there is extra symbols `,"` after `fullname`. This can not be an object. Where and how did you create this JSON?

Comment: @Beartums I did use console.dir() and it responded the same. , right now my backend is NodeJS and I use the latest moongoose scheme http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html for parsing. But the first json listed is exactly the json in the MongoDB database. So I dont see how it can be changing

Comment: @Epsilon sorry that was a typo

Comment: @Epsilon as I said in an above comment, I use moongoose on the Node JS side for parsing. And the first JSON I listed is exactly how it is in the database. My app is angular and it uses http which gives me back a json object I don't have to parse on client side.

Comment: About 'EDIT', I believe `dat[0]` is still typo.

Comment: @MiguelSamor, maybe the Mongoose schema?  Any chance Mongoose thinks those objects are strings? Following on the comment by Epsilon, you might want to look into your MongoDB.  I used to use something calle -- I believe -- roboMongo to look through the database.  That might give you and idea.

Comment: @MiguelSamor Then you should see the place, where you wrote it into mongo, because they are strings `[object Object]` instead of real objects.

Comment: Your JSON is legal, what parser you are using?

Comment: It's returning `undefined` because `items` is string '[object Object]' and and therefore `items['username']` is nothing.

Comment: @Epsilon I am currently restructuring my server code, will come back with response shortly.

Comment: @Epsilon My server is now written properly, I will explain in an answer to this question. Thank you for you input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look closely at data[0]:  posts contains an array of two *strings* that say "[object Object]", not two objects.  How are you parsing the json?

oh, and your syntax is correct for extracting the username from the nested objects

Comment: My guess is that he's calling `toString` somewhere on each actual post object.

Comment: Andras you were correct, I will create an answer with explanation

Comment: THIS was the correct answer. In my mongoDB, I remembered I had manually entered what I thought was correct data into my "posts" array in that JSON. All looked well in mongoDB (as I posted in my question) however I guess by manually inputting I did not write the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

if variable `dat` holds your json object. Then you can try below code to access username in your json:

```
dat.posts[0].username
```